# построение таблицы с данными

Tags: php

Коллеги прошу помощи в построении таблицы мне не нужно решении прошу подсказку в реализации, пока что не понимаю как правильно наполнять по оси х или y

есть данные

```
$arr = [
0=>[
    "countGroup" => [
        0 => [
            "count_groups" => '5',
            "count" => '3'
        ],
        1 => [
            "count_groups" => '6',
            "count" => '5'
        ],
        2 => [
            "count_groups" => '7',
            "count" => '21'
        ],

    ],
    'city' => "CITY_1"
],
1=>[
    "countGroup" => [
        0 => [
            "count_groups" => '6',
            "count" => '4'
        ],
        1 => [
            "count_groups" => '7',
            "count" => '5'
        ],
        2 => [
            "count_groups" => '10',
            "count" => '21'
        ],

    ],
    'city' => "CITY_2"
],
```

];

нужно получить таблицу вида

```
город  \ наполняемость  10   7   6  5
CITY_1                  -   21   5  3
CITY_2                  21   5   4  -
```

верхняя строка это максимальный показатель (count) по городам а ниже это количество count_groups

то есть как в примере при максимальном 10 у нас есть в городе CITY_2 21 группа 
при показателе 7 у нас есть   CITY_1  - 21 группа и в  CITY_2   - 5 и 
т.д

не могу понять как правильно разбить и сгруппировать массивы и возможно ли это сделать в один перебор

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем что-либо выводить необходимо данные привести в удобный для этого формат. В данном случае, чтобы успешно выводить таблицу вам нужно перечислить строки и знать столбцы. И если строки вам известны, то надо собрать полный набор столбцов.

Для удобства лучше представить исходный массив несколько в ином виде заменив

```
    0 => [
        "count_groups" => '5',
        "count" => '3'
    ],
```

на

```
5 => 3
```

Ведь первое значение это у вас идентификатор группы, а второе - значение? вот и сделайте их ключом массива и его значением. Если это можно сделать на уровне выборки данных, то хорошо, если нет, то, например, так:

```
$arr = array_map(function(&$c){
                  $c['countGroup'] = array_column($c['countGroup'], 'count', 'count_groups');
                  return $c;
             },$arr);
```

Далее надо взять все доступные уникальные ключи групп слить в один массив и, видимо, отсортировать:

```
$cols = array_reduce(array_map(function($c){ 
                           return array_keys($c['countGroup']);
                        }, $arr),
               'array_merge', []);
$cols = array_unique($cols);
```

Теперь вы можете писать цикл по строкам `$arr`, и вложенный цикл по столбцам `$cols`:

```
foreach($arr as $row){
    // $row['city']
    foreach($cols as $cIdx){
       // $row['countGroup'][$cIdx] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое все красиво получилось